# Scala iterable and java iterable

Tags: java, scala, compatibility

I'm working on a java lib in scala.

I got something like this:

```
def myFunc(): Thing[Iterable[T]] = {
  // call java lib for the result
  ...
  javaResult  // Problem: it's Thing[java.lang.Iterable[T]]
}
```

So you see the problem is that the return type of the java thing is `Thing[java.lang.Iterable[T]]`. I've tried importing `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` but that doesn't work. Note that I don't have access to the java lib and I'm not able to extract that iterable then reconstruct a Thing object with a scala one.

I can annotate the return type as `java.lang.Iterable` but as scala and java are designed to be work together, I'm wondering if there's some way to solve this problem elegantly?

Comment: You cannot solve this, without specifics about `Thing`. If its a monad (or a monad-like structure), just call `map(_.asScala)` on it.

Comment: Nitpick: Scala is designed to work with Java, not vice versa ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Designed to work together" means exactly that you can return `Thing[java.lang.Iterable[T]]`.
It does look like it is your only option.